# How to insert data submitted from an HTML form into a Redis database?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to save the user-submitted HTTP data into Redis. This is my code using Nickel:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nickel;
extern crate redis;
extern crate hyper;

use redis::{Client,Parser, Commands, Connection, RedisResult};
use nickel::{Nickel, Request, Response, HttpRouter, MiddlewareResult,Middleware, MediaType,JsonBody};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use nickel::status::StatusCode;
use nickel_redis::{RedisMiddleware, RedisRequestExtensions};
use hyper::Url;
use url::form_urlencoded;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn save_db<'a>(req: &mut Request, res: Response<'a>) -> MiddlewareResult<'a> {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();
    /* FIXME: connect redis*/ 
    let client = Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/").unwrap();
    let conn = client.get_connection().unwrap();

    server.post("/confirmation", middleware!{|req, res|
        let mut form_data = String::new();
        req.origin.read_to_string(&mut form_data).unwrap();
        let _: () = conn.set("contents", form_data).unwrap();
        println!("{}", form_data);

        let mut data = HashMap::<&str, String>::new();
        data.insert("content", form_data);
        data.insert("page_title", "Save blog data".to_string());
        return res.render("app/views/blog/save.tpl", &data);
    });
}

fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();

    // start using router
    let mut router = Nickel::router();
    let client = Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/").unwrap();
    let conn = client.get_connection().unwrap();

    router.get("/test-save-db", save_db);

    server.utilize(router);
    server.listen("127.0.0.12:8080");
}
```

**Save.tpl**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Saved new blog.</h1>
    <h2>Author {{form_data}}</h2>
    <h2>Content {{content}}</h2>
    <form>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" >
    <br>
    <button type="submit" formenctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" formaction="/test-save-db" formmethod="post">SEND</button>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

But I get this error

> error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'b` due to conflicting requirements [E0495](req.origin.read_to_string(&mut form_data).unwrap();)

Comment: Why are you creating a new Nickel server inside of what looks like a Nickel request handler? I would only expect there to be one server at a time.

Comment: If I don't create a new Nickel server, I won't call function server.post(). Do you how to solve problem?

Comment: You haven't provided an [MCVE](/help/mcve) (emphasis first on the **C** and then the **M**), so I cannot compile your code to give any useful feedback. I'm pretty sure this code isn't using Nickel correctly, but I cannot guess why the line you've highlighted (`req.origin.read_to_string(&mut form_data).unwrap()`) would cause the error you've stated.

Comment: I just need save the user-submitted HTTP data into Redis with let _: () = conn.set("contents", form_data).unwrap();. it doesn't work.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/424aqs/how_to_insert_data_submitted_from_an_html_form/)

Comment: It's me. I post it  to Reddit. So, can you help me solve problem?

Comment: Even though you updated your code, it still doesn't reproduce the problem you say it does. There are unknown imports (`nickel_redis `, `url`) and other errors (`the trait \`core::marker::Sync\` is not implemented for the type \`core::cell::UnsafeCell<redis::connection::ActualConnection>\``). It's also a good idea to include the versions of libraries so that we can use the same ones. If you are unable to produce a minimal case that **reproduces your error**, it will be very hard for *anyone* to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see in your code is that you're trying to register a handler for a route (POST `/confirmation`) inside the handler that gets called when the `/test-save-db` route is matched. That doesn't seem correct.

To make your code and intent clearer, I suggest you use the `middleware!` macro, which I find to be the simplest way to describe routes in Nickel. At least this has been my experience since starting to use the framework yesterday :-)

So your example might be rewritten as follows:

```
fn main() {
    let client = Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/").unwrap();
    let mut server = Nickel::new();

    server.get("/test-save-db", middleware! { |req, res|
        // do something with the request and send a response
    });

    server.listen("127.0.0.12:8080");
}
```

If you need multiple handlers sharing the same client, you will need to use `std::sync::Arc` to have thread safe shared state, and clone it for each handler (it will only clone the `Arc`, not the client).